# Must I ceremonially dispatch a non-kosher animal meant for Gentile consumption?

Tags: tefilla, slaughter-shochet-shecht, non-kosher-species

I raise non-kosher animals (rabbits) primarily for manure for my garden and fur for clothing.  I give the meat away to non-Jews.  I understand all domesticated animals are to be humanely killed, regardless of intended use, if killing is called for. Is there a prayer to say before dispatching, even though I am not a trained shochet?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/23319/5323

Answer (score 3):

Kosher slaughter is not simply any humane method of slaughter. It is a specific procedure, with precise details that must be followed.

One does not need to follow this procedure when slaughtering animals for most non-food purposes, including clothing. However, you should slaughter the animal humanely, becaue there is a separate prohibition against causing unnecessary pain to animals.

One does not make a blessing if they are not following this procedure.

There is a rabbinic prohibition against dealing in non-kosher food, but it is allowed if the non-kosher food is a side-effect of the business. One example of this is that when Kosher slaughterers inspect animals after they kill them, any animals found to be non-kosher are sold to non-Jews.

Comment: Good answer, just one point: "One does not need to follow this procedure when slaughtering animals for most non-food purposes" -- see שמלה חדשה at [1:21](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35269&st=&pgnum=14) that the procedure must be followed; and [19:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35269&st=&pgnum=78) that the blessing is made. HOWEVER, I do not believe that there is a שחיטה procedure outlined for rabbits; they not only do not have the correct signs for being a kosher animal, they may be a paradigm of non-kosher, as the arnevet (rabbit or hare.) In any event, yes be humane