# Are there laws for slaughtering non-kosher animals?

Tags: halacha

The method of ritual slaughter of animals that we eat is meant to be as painless as possible.

What laws of slaughter apply to animals we do not eat (such as animals we use for dog food), be they intrinsically non-kosher (e.g. no split hooves) or a treifa (e.g., dying due to injury)?

Comment: "is meant to be as painless as possible" under common premodern circumstances. It's not literally meant to the be the least painful way possible always.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shechting non-Kosher animals](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23319/shechting-non-kosher-animals)

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi  The post you link to is related but does not ask the same question as my post above.

Answer (score 1):

None. The laws of slaughter are primarily meant to render an animal kosher for Jewish consumption. That is why an animal that died a natural death is forbidden, even though no one made it suffer.

While an animal killed for another reason should presumably be killed as humanely as possible, there is no reason to assume shechitah is the only way to do so. Presumably there are other- possibly easier- ways to painlessly kill an animal.

Comment: Sources would strengthen this answer.